# reception area price

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question:
The carpet chosen by Callis International for their reception area was $16.75 a square yard. What price should the store quote for the carpet if the reception area was 12 ft. by 6 in. by 8 ft.?

I'm not quite sure how to approach this question since I don't understand how you can find the area using 3 measurements. I can't tell if it's the surface area I need to find because reception areas are flat surfaces. The answer provided was $418.75. I tried working backwards from the answer, but I could not figure out how to area is 25 yards.

Comment: Convert the lengths from feet and inches to yards.

Comment: Most probably, one length was 12ft + 6in, so that makes 2 measurements. Still that doesn't explain the answer given.

Comment: I've already tried that. What am I supposed to do with the 3 lengths though?

Comment: I'm guessing they meant "12 ft, 6 in by 18 ft", which is $\frac {25}{6} \text{ yd } \times 6 \text{ yd } = 25\text{ yd}$. But whoever was supposed to proofread this question didn't do their job.